# Potential workaround to inotifywait can't produce NUL-delimited output

Tags: bash, shell-script, security, filenames, inotify

I'm currently writing a bash script that uses [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to perform certain actions on a user-supplied list of files and directories.

[It has come to my attention](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/issues/20) that unlike a lot of shell tools, `inotifywait` is unable to separate output records with `\0`.  This leaves [the possibility of injection attacks](https://www.reddit.com/r/coding/comments/2b7npr/how_to_use_inotifytools_to_trigger_scripts_on/) with specifically crafted, but legal filenames (containing newlines).

I would like to work around this to ensure my script does not introduce any unnecessary vulnerabilities.  My approach is as folllows:

- Ensure all files/paths passed for `inotifywait` to watch have trailing backslashes removed
- Format `inotifywait` output with `--format "%e %w%f//"` to produce output as follows:

  - `<EVENT LIST> <FILE PATH>//`
- Pipe `inotifywait` output to sed; any `//` found at the ends of lines with `\0`
- Use bash `while read` loop to read `\0`-separated records
- This means after the first record, all following records will have an extra leading newline.  This is stripped off
- Each record may then be split at the first space - before the space is the event list (comma separated as per inotifywait) - and after the space the full pathname associated with the event

```bash
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
watchlist=("${@}")

# Remove trailing slashes from any watchlist elements
watchlist=("${watchlist[@]%%+(/)}")

# Reduce multiple consecutive slashes to singles as per @meuh
watchlist=("${watchlist[@]//+(\/)/\/}")

printf -vnewline "\n"

inotifywait -qrm "${watchlist[@]}" --format "%e %w%f//" | \
    sed -u 's%//$%\x00%' | \
    while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
        line="${line#${newline}}"
        events="${line%% *}"
        filepath="${line#* }"
        printf "events=%s\nfilepath=%q\n" "$events" "$filepath"
    done
```

As far as I can tell, this handles file/path names containing funny characters - spaces, newlines, quotes, etc.  But it seems like a rather inelegant kludge.

For the purposes of this question, the `${watchlist[]}` array is just copied from command-line parameters, but this array may be build otherwise and may contain "funny" characters.

1. Are there any malicious paths that could break this? i.e. make the contents of the `$events` and `$filepath` variables be incorrect for any given event?
2. If this is water-tight, is there any cleaner way to do this?

Note I know I could easily write a [c](/questions/tagged/c) program to call `inotify_add_watch()` and friends to get around this.  But for now due to other dependencies I am working in bash.

---

I've been conflicted on whether to post this here or codereview.SE or even the main so.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to sanitize `watchlist` to replace any `//` with `/`. Consider a directory named `\nabc` (where `\n` is a newline):

```
$ mkdir t
$ mkdir t/$'\nabc'
$ touch t/$'\nabc'/x
```

If passed the directory `t//$'\nabc'` you will see output with bogus `//` at the end of lines:

```
$ inotifywait -m -r t//$'\nabc' --format "%e %w%f//" 
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
OPEN t//
abc/x//
ATTRIB t//
abc/x//
CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE t//
abc/x//
```

Note, you could also use `-c` instead of `--format` to get *csv* style output, which double-quotes filenames with newlines, but it is harder to parse, and in my case core dumps on the above example.

Example output for `-c` and `touch t/$'new\nfile'`:

```
t/,CREATE,"new
file"
```

Comment: Thanks, good catch.  I've edited this suggestion into my question.

Comment: As for CSV, the inotifywait version I have segfaults for filenames containing newlines in CSV mode.  E.g. `touch new$'\n'line` `inotifywait -c new$'\n'line &` `touch new$'\n'line`.  Non-CSV mode does not crash with this filename.  I built the latest from source and it looks like this crash has been fixed, but unfortunately I'm restricted to an older version on my embedded platform.

Answer (score 4):

There is [fork](https://github.com/813gan/inotify-tools) that supports NUL-delimited output, You can use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
watchlist=("${@}")

# Remove trailing slashes from any watchlist elements
watchlist=("${watchlist[@]%%+(/)}")

printf -vnewline "\n"

inotifywait -qrm "${watchlist[@]}" --format "%e %w%f%0" | \
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
    events="${line%% *}"
    filepath="${line#* }"
    printf "events=%s\nfilepath=%q\n" "$events" "$filepath"
done
```

Note this version does not add newline by default when --format is used.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately for now I need to work with the existing inotifywait version in the embedded platform I am working on.  Good info though.